# Topological space such that each closed can be spanned by a finite set

Tags: general-topology

In a branch of topology, namely the convexity spaces theory, the main objects that are investigated are infinite topological spaces where the closure operation $cl$ has the following property:

$$
cl(A)=\bigcup\limits_{F \subseteq A \\ F \, finite} cl(F)
$$

Moreover, the following definition is classically provided: let $C$ be a closed set. Then a subset $B$ is said to span $C$ if $cl(B)=C$.

My questions are:

1) Are there examples of topological spaces such that each closed set is spanned by at least a finite set?

2) Moreover, are there examples of topological spaces such that each closed set is spanned only by finite sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $X$ equipped with indiscrete topology.

2) Every closed set is spanned by itself so if it is spanned *only* by finite sets then it must be finite. However the whole space $X$ is closed so if *each* closed set is spanned only by finite set then the whole space must be finite. In that case every closed subset of $X$ is finite hence  is spanned by closed set (itself) and can only be spanned by finite sets (there are no sets available that are not finite).

Comment: Are there other non-trivial examples for point 1)?

Comment: Another example: let $x\in X$ and define $A\subseteq X$ to be closed if $A=\varnothing$ or $x\in A$. That's also kind of trivial, though. I can't think of any non-trivials. In a $T_1-$space (weak condition) finite sets are closed, so only span themselves.